# What to do about the same question in two different languages

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, language-versions

This is the first time that I've seen this happen.

In regards to the following question on the English version of Stack Overflow:

- [Removing html tags without breaking lines with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46776728/removing-html-tags-without-breaking-lines-with-php)

The OP is Portuguese and I noticed they also posted what appears to be the same question on the Portuguese version of the network:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/246571/retirar-tags-html-sem-quebrar-linhas-com-php

Edit: The above (Portuguese) post seems to now have been deleted after rechecking it.

I figured it was a duplicate repost and was going to close it as such, but I got the following message pop up in red when I tried to do it:

> got back The duplicate question must exist on Stack Overflow

How should this have been handled and was it considered as being a repost? Should they or are they allowed to post the same question on different areas of the network?